# How to show control characters Unicode in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, unicode, javafx-11

I'm using javafx 11 and jdk 8 to make a program which you can write something in a textarea and it will do some operation on that text, then it will show to result to you.
The problem is that I want to paste some special characters of unicode like "U+0011 :  DEVICE CONTROL ONE [DC1]" but when I paste in the input textarea It will not appear.
Is there any way to make these kind of characters appear and get used?
These chars appear in notepad++ like this:

[image: DC1 in notepad++]

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: How are you using JavaFX 11 on Java 8?

Comment: Well to be honest, I don't know how did I get it running on jdk 8; I'm using Intellij IDEA, so I just downgraded the jdk after I added javafx 11 to my modules and library. I don't think it would need a reproducible example because It's the most simple TextArea , and to reproduce what I talked about you can just copy and paste a [DC1] char into that TextArea to see it.

Comment: Remember that Java 8 bundled JavaFX with the JDK, at least in Oracle distributions. I wouldn't be surprised if none of the classes from the JavaFX 11 modules are being loaded; otherwise I'd expect a `UnsupportedClassVersionError` since JavaFX 11 targets Java 11+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears JavaFX is stripping control characters before inserting text.

You can’t show the characters directly, but Unicode has a block of characters specifically for showing control characters:  [Control Pictures](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Control_Pictures).

So, showing a visual representation of a character is as easy as:

```
char charToDisplay = (c >= 32 || c == '\n' ? c : (char) (c + 0x2400));
```

You can transform any String fairly easily:

```
static String makeControlCharactersVisible(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return s;
    }

    int len = s.length();
    StringBuilder visible = new StringBuilder(len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        visible.append(c >= 32 || c == '\n' ? c : (char) (c + 0x2400));
    }

    return visible.toString();
}
```

In a JavaFX text component, you can intercept the paste:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea() {
    @Override
    public void paste() {
        String text = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
        replaceSelection(makeControlCharactersVisible(text));
    }
};
```

There are two disadvantages to this:

- Most fonts have terrible glyphs for the control pictures characters, which are barely readable at normal font sizes like 12 points.
- It’s conceivable that a user might want to actually paste a control picture character, in which case there would be no way to know whether they pasted, for example, `'\u0011'` or `'\u2411'`.